# How can I save file by using savetxt in the python?

Tags: python, numpy, file-io

I have lists of data such as

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,0]
c = [0,0,0,0,0]
```

I want to save this data into a file in a form of

1 6 0

2 7 0

3 8 0

4 9 0

5 0 0

I can do this by using "open". But I want to go with savetxt.

How can I save the data into the above form by using savetxt?

Comment: This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask], [mre] and the other links found on those pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import numpy as np


a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
b = np.array([6, 7, 8, 9, 0])
c = np.array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0])

all_data = np.vstack([a, b, c])

np.savetxt("data.txt", all_data.T, fmt="%d")
```

`all_data` stack the arrays rows by rows, so to print the data the way you want it you need to print the transpose, so `all_data.T`

You also need to format the output, so `%d`

Answer (score 1):

**A.T**

```
import numpy as np

a = [1,2,3,4,5]
b = [6,7,8,9,0]
c = [0,0,0,0,0]

A = np.array([a,b,c])
B = A.T
np.savetxt("./demo1",B,fmt="%d")
```

we can use `numpy` let a,b,c become a
3x3 matrix
and use the `transpose` way of numpy
`A`:

```
[[1 2 3 4 5]  
 [6 7 8 9 0]  
 [0 0 0 0 0]]
```

`A.T`

```
[[1 6 0]  
 [2 7 0]  
 [3 8 0]  
 [4 9 0]  
 [5 0 0]]
```

then we can use

```
np.savetxt("./demo1",B,fmt="%d")
```

`"./demo1"`:  file name
`B`: data
`fmt="%d"`:  format